# Maven dependancy for hive jdbc can not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, hive

I want to connect to hive database using `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` driver and added dependancy in pom.xml file:

Does any dependencies here have conflict with hive-jdbc?

Comment: Have you included the other libraries as dependencies in your project? I suspect they might be related dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project. Go to Maven Update project, then check the above option “**Force update of Snapshot/Releases**" click OK in Eclipse. this clears all errors.

Comment: I tried mvn -U clean install but not worked